# zsh complete cd with two arguments

Tags: linux, zsh

Context for those who know about zsh completion but not all its features: 
One of the unique and really useful features of zsh is as follows:

```
[/usr/dir1/dir2/dir3/]$ cd dir1 dirnew
/usr/dirnew/dir2/dir3
[/usr/dirnew/dir2/dir3]$
```

i.e. If a user can replace a particular directory in the hierarchy with another. Its a very handy feature. (assuming dirnew does have dir2/dir3). If dirnew didn't have dir2/dir3, this command would fail.

I wonder how I can complete cd though, for long directory names. When I do `cd <TAB>`, besides the directories in the current directory, what should also show up is directories in the current hierarchy. Once I choose or type in one of the directories from the hierarchy, if I press `<TAB>` again, I should get completion options from the directories in parent which have a similar hierarchy. In the above example, say /usr/ has dirnew and diranother beisdes dir1. dirnew has dir2/dir3 but diranother is empty.
`cd dir1 <TAB>` should give me new as an option, but not diranother.

Answer (score 2):

Either you have an old version of Zsh or your configuration is breaking it. Zsh's `cd` completion has that feature and it works. You can verify it by running zsh without using any of your configs:

```
zsh -f # all settings at their default values
autoload compinit && compinit
mkdir -p tmp/a/b
mkdir -p tmp/c/b
mkdir -p tmp/b
cd tmp/a/b
cd a [TAB]
```

I am running Zsh 5.1 and it completes correctly to `c`. If I create a second possible completion, e.g. `mkdir -p d/b`, it gives me `c` and `d`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer although I'm on zsh 5.0 and don't see this, so would try out otherwise and then answer.

Comment: I don't think this is new. Did you try the script with your zsh?

Comment: I did, yes. I follwed your exact steps and couldn't get it working. But thanks for the help.